# How to use OpenGL SL for general computing

Tags: opengl-es, cuda, opencl

I know OpenCL and CUDA. These are not support in mobile device. But most of them support OpenGL ES. So I want to learn using OpenGL ES shading language for general computing.  Like OpenCL or CUDA, in OpenGLSL.

- How many kinds of buffer can I use?  what are they?
- How to manipulate  these buffers

As I know， I can create vertex and fragment shader so far.

- Which buffer can I manipulate when I use fragment shader
- Which buffer can I manipulate when I use vertex shader
- **Are there any synchronized function in GPU(I mean synchronization in GPU. like the thread synchronized in the block in OpenCL or CUDA)**

**PS:**
I read a paper [Using Mobile GPU for General-Purpose Computing](http://lbmedia.ece.ucsb.edu/resources/ref/vlsidat11.pdf). Their experiments were performed on an Nvidia Tegra SoC with the following specifications:

1. 1GHz dual-core ARM Cortex-A9 CPU,
2. 1GB of RAM
3. an Nvidia ultra-low-power GeForce GPU running at 333MHz, and 512MB of Flash memory

It can get 3X speedup on FFT(128*128). I think these result is good. Do you guys think if it's worth to do it. So the main bottleneck is the memory access right?

**As many guys said it's not worth to do general purpose computing on OpenGL ES. So it's not worth to expect the mobile supporting OpenCL either. Right? In my opinion, OpenGL ES is the fomentation of the OpenCL**

Comment: Which platform are you targeting?

Comment: @TraxNet: I don't know now. But I think it should support opengl ES 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some platforms don't support any floating point formats. Some platforms (powervr, tegra, adreno) support half-float (16bit float) surfaces, which can be used both as a render target and as a texture. Full float support exists on some platforms (adreno, and I believe the latest powervr), but is rather rare.

So it depends a lot on what kind of calculation you're expecting to do, what kind of precision is acceptable for you, as well as what your target platform is.

Also take into account the fact that current-gen opengl es (2.0) does not have full IEEE float requirements, so the results may vary.

In the end, whether it is worth it depends a lot on your batch sizes though; accessing the results (i.e, reading pixels back from the render target) may be so slow that it negates the performance gain.

To address your bullet-points one by one:

- How many kinds of buffer can I use? what are they?

You can create a texture and form a FBO out of that. Additionally you can feed data to the shaders as constants (uniforms) or per-vertex data streams (varyings/attribs).

- How to manipulate these buffers

You can write to a texture using the normal texture handling functions.

- Which buffer can I manipulate when I use fragment shader

When a FBO is bound, you can write to it using the fragment shader. Later, you can access the results by reading from the texture you bound to the FBO.

- Which buffer can I manipulate when I use vertex shader

None.

- Are there any synchronized function in GPU

You can flush the pipeline using glFinish(). The drivers should cause a pipeline flush implicitly if you try to access the texture data, though.

Comment: As of today (2012-12-17), on android, that is the right answer.

Comment: @Jari Komppa: I think the platform should support the OpenGL ES 2.0. And can support 32bit float. Actually I have little knowledge about GLSL. I can't find more material about SL on general purpose computing

Comment: @TraxNet - true, OpenGL ES 3.0 and hardware designed for it will change the picture completely.

Comment: @Samuel - I'm fairly certain this is the case mostly because it's not worth it, if only for the reason texture->memory fetch is so slow. There *may* be a shortcut on iOS.

Comment: While half float textures are supported by all iOS devices that support OpenGL ES 2.0, only the latest ones support rendering to half-float targets (iPad 2, 3, iPhone 5, and I believe 4S). Some of the particulars are mentioned here: http://volcore.limbic.com/2011/10/23/hdr-rendering-on-ios-ipad2iphone-4s/ . None of them are full-float yet that I'm aware of. As far as faster reading from rendered output, iOS does allow for direct memory access to textures since 5.0 by using texture caches. This can avoid glReadPixels() and speed up some read operations by a significant amount.

Comment: @Jari Komppa: Can I manipulate texture directly instead of bounding a FBO. And the vertex shader is used to generate the address ID for each thread for next step in fragment shader. right? Or don't need vertex shader

Comment: @samuel If you want to manipulate a texture with the GPU, you need to bind it to an FBO. You also need at least a minimal vertex shader, as the only way to render pixels is to draw geometry - basically you'll probably just want a rectangle (or 2 triangles).

Comment: @Jari Komppa: My last question `Are there any synchronized function in GPU`. I mean synchronizing in GPU , not in CPU. Like block synchronizing in CUDA or OpenCL

Comment: @Samuel I don't think it applies directly.. when you read from a texture you've rendered to, the driver will make sure any write operations have finished before letting you read from the texture.

Answer (score 1):

Before my forays into OpenCL when I had large quantities of numeric data i would feed it to the GPU using the numeric data as pixel data via an rgba image, and then manipulate it: its a nice fast way to approach large number sets for mathematical manipulation, although you then have to copy from the buffer back to the CPU to be able to extract the changes, so it depends on how much data you need to manipulate this way as to whether it is worth it, as well as how much graphics RAM you have available and the number of cores etc.